# Binding to normal List property does not work

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, collections, binding

I have the following XAML in my Xamarin.Forms project:

```xml
<FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FilterManager.FilteredBookViewModels}" Wrap="Wrap" >
  <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>                                        
      <Label Text="DOES NOT WORK" ></Label>
    </DataTemplate>
  </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
<FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FilterManager.FilteredBooksViewModels2}" Wrap="Wrap" >
  <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>                                        
      <Label Text="WORKS" ></Label>
    </DataTemplate>
  </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
```

In my viewmodel I have the following code.

```cs
public List<LibraryBookViewModel2> FilteredBookViewModels { get; } = new List<LibraryBookViewModel2>();

public List<LibraryBookViewModel2> FilteredBookViewModels2
{
  get { return FilteredBookViewModels.ToList(); }
}

private void TriggerUiRefresh()
{
  OnPropertyChanged("FilteredBookViewModels");
  OnPropertyChanged("FilteredBookViewModels2");
}
```

Whenever the list changes, I call TriggerUiRefresh.

The problem is that only the flexlayout that is bound to FilteredBookViewModels2 shows it's items in the UI. I'm puzzled as to why that is the case. What's wrong with my "normal" property?

This problem occurs in UWP (didn't check the Android / iOS yet).

Answer (score 0):

For Binding to work you need to have a backing property, then only INotifyPropertyChanged will work as expected.

For `FilteredBookViewModels2` you have a backing property `FilteredBookViewModels`, but `FilteredBookViewModels` doesn't have a backing property.

This should have been your ViewModel :-

```cs
private List<LibraryBookViewModel2> _filteredBookViewModels;
public List<LibraryBookViewModel2> FilteredBookViewModels
{
    get { return _filteredBookViewModels; }
    set => SetProperty(ref _filteredBookViewModels, value);
}

private List<LibraryBookViewModel2> _filteredBookViewModels2;
public List<LibraryBookViewModel2> FilteredBookViewModels2
{
    get { return _filteredBookViewModels2; }
    set => SetProperty(ref _filteredBookViewModels2, value);
}

private void TriggerUiRefresh()
{
   OnPropertyChanged("FilteredBookViewModels");
   OnPropertyChanged("FilteredBookViewModels2");
}
```

If you replace the above code with mine it should work.

Let me know for further queries. Thanks!